# I want to switch to another page after clicking on the pic in codeigniter, how i can do it?

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter, web

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <a href="#" class="portfolio-box">
               <img src="img/portfolio/1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                    <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
                        <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
                            <div class="project-category text-faded">
                                Category:-
                            </div>
                            <div class="project-name">
                                Mobile
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
```

//1.jpg image is appearing in the view i want to switch to another view after clicking on this image.

Comment: i got the solution by implementing <a href="index.php/name_of_controller" class="portfolio-box">

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this with css:

```
#my-div{
background-color: #000;
width: 200px;
height: 200px } 
a.fill-div {
display: block;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
text-decoration: none}


<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6" id="my-div">
        <a href="#" class="portfolio-box"> </a>
          the rest of it.
        </div>
```